# UINavigationController: pushViewController not working in iOS 13, remains on same page

Tags: objective-c, ios13

I am calling a method from **performSelectorOnMainThread** which calls **pushViewController**. But the view is not loaded and remains on the same page. This case was working in iOS 12 but not in iOS 13.

```
- (void)toNextView:{
    ImageViewController * vc = ImageViewController.new;
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(nextScreenWithVC:) withObject:vc waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

```
- (void)nextScreenWithVC:(UIViewController *)vc
{
    [self.parent.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
}
```

This function does not loads the ImageViewController. The same code works in iOS 12.

Comment: Are you see any warning or error message on XCode  when calling  nextScreenWithVC function ?

Comment: Sounds like self.parent or self.parent.navigationController evaluates to nil.

Comment: Thanks @Groot, i investigated and fount that self.parent.navigationController evaluates to nil. I will investigate more why it is null for iOS 13 and not for iOS 12.

Comment: @MirzohidAkbarov, there are no warring or error messages. I am using Xcode 10.1

Comment: Also, shouldn’t it be `parentViewController` in Objective-C?

Comment: Did you solve this @Vinay

Comment: @Groot, Yeah i got the reason why self.parent.navigationController is nil. The function call sequence got changed for iOS 13. So nextScreenWithVC function was called before initializing the navigationController. Now i am changing the function call sequence to work with iOS12 and before and also on iOS13.

Comment: @Vinay Can you please guide in detail. How changing the sequence, what is the issue actually?

Comment: @iPhone7 the app is going in background state before calling pushViewController and another app is opened for processing. After the processing is done the callback function for the app was invoked after returning to foreground and pushViewController was getting proper viewContoller in iOS12. But due to increase in processing speed and multi threading the callback function for the app was not called in proper sequence, instead viewWillEnterForeground() was process and was calling pushViewController which was null. Thus moved some callback logic into viewWillEnterForeground() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution by reading the iOS 13 release note. To understand some changes i used the following link.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle?language=objc

The app is going in background state before calling pushViewController and another app is opened for processing. After the processing is done the callback function for the app was invoked after returning to foreground and pushViewController was getting proper viewContoller in iOS12. But due to increase in processing speed and multi threading the callback function for the app was not called in required sequence, instead viewWillEnterForeground() was called which must be the default correct order and was calling pushViewController which was null. Thus moved some callback logic into viewWillEnterForeground() function and now it is working for iOS13 and iOS12 and bellow.